# I want to deselect the checkboxes on button click

Tags: angular, checkbox

i want to implement *clear all filters* feature, for that i need to deselect all the checkboxes on a button click.

I have used primeng checkbox.
HTML:

```
<button (click)="clearAllFilters()">Clear All Filters</button>

<p-checkbox *ngFor="let cb of filterColorCheckboxes" value="{{cb.value}}"
    label="{{cb.value | titlecase}}" (onChange)="checkBoxFilter(cb.category, cb.value, $event)">
</p-checkbox>
```

In *event.checked*, i am getting an array of length 1 containing the value of the checkbox (instead of any boolean value that is given in many other solutions). That's why am unable to deselect the checkbox.

Comment: What's clearAllFilters doing?
event.checked on an click event?

A Minimal, Reproducible Example is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ngModel to do this?

```
import { Component, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';
import { Checkbox } from 'primeng/checkbox';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChildren('checkbox') checkboxes: QueryList<Checkbox>;
  selectedCities: string[] = [];

  filterColorCheckboxes: any[] = [
    { value: false, label: 'A' },
    { value: false, label: 'M' },
    { value: false, label: 'P' },
    { value: false, label: 'R' },
  ];

  checked: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit() {}

  clearAllFilters() {
    console.log('clear');
    this.filterColorCheckboxes.forEach((x) => {
      x.value = false;
    });
  }

  checkBoxFilter(...argt) {
    console.log(argt);
  }
}
```

html

```
<mat-slider
  thumbLabel
  tickInterval="1000"
  min="1"
  max="100000"
  class="cdk-focused"
></mat-slider
>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-checkbox-demo-g5uq3g)

Comment: @AyushiGupta does this answer help you?

Comment: *x.value = false; * this part is not giving the desired result